# trying to rebuild RAID 5 array with failed drive, `/dev/sdc1 has no superblock - assembly aborted`

Tags: raid, software-raid, raid5

I have ~20TB MD array spanned across 5 6TB hard drives. yesterday one of the drives failed and the system stopped booting. I'm not very good at Linux, so whenever this happened in the past, I'd simply reinstall Debian, and run any requisite `mdadm` commands that might be necessary to get the array running again (after picking up a spare HD from my local store). specifically, I remove the old drive from the system, run `mdadm --assemble` and then add the new drive to the array so it gets provisioned over the next day or so.

This time around, when I run `mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sd{a,c,d,f}1 --force`, it fails complaining that `No super block found on /dev/sdc1 (expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)`.

for some context, those 4 drives (sd{a,c,d,f}) are new hard drives, bought in the past 3 months. the drive that would be the fifth (which I removed and replaced with one of the new ones), is five years old.

while sdc could be the failed drive (I'm about to test), It's more likely that it's the old one. My backup is also a bit old, about 2 months old now. tbh I don't even know where to start. I've done some googling but it all seems very arcane to this mere mortal and I'm very frightened that one false step might cause me to lose all my data (if I haven't already).

I can provide logs of what I'm doing now. my current system is Debian 12 running on a Hyper-V host. would appreciate any help.

Comment: You say you're using 5 6TB drives, is that correct? When you assemble the array, why are you only including 4?

Comment: one of them failed. I am not including that drive. to be clear, the system won't boot if that drive is connected

Comment: I believe you're supposed to still build the array with five drives, but in the place of the one that has failed you use the keyword "missing".

Comment: But if `sdc1` is showing with no superblock, and is in fact one of the drives that used to be in the array, you are quite possibly SOL. I'll note that on one of the machines where I have RAID5 happening, the order of the drives is not constant across boots; sometimes I'm booting off `sdj1`, sometimes off `sdc1`, what drive does what seems to key on GUID.

Comment: what is SOL? I'm reading this to mean I'm screwed. Thanks for the help. time to get the back-up, I guess

Comment: SOL is "s**t out of luck". Yeah, you may be; but first thing I'd do is check to see if `sdc1` is actually showing as part of a RAID set. If you're using a GUI desktop, look for an app `Disks` in the All Programs menu; that will show you all your drives, and allow you to determine the letters assigned to your remaining RAID drives.

Comment: I don't have a GUI. it's just an empty debian 12 system with ssh server and mdadm installed

Comment: Try `sudo parted -l` (lower-case L for the option). That should list all your partitions, tell you which drives are associated with the RAID volume.

Comment: for some reason sdc was empty, all it had was an msr (microsoft recovery) partition, which is weird because the drive was offline and untouched by the hypervisor. Oh well, I ended up remaking the array from scratch with a backup I had from a month ago or two. thanks for the help, would've probably taken a while longer to figure out without. I now have a spare drive, to make it harder to end up with 2 failed, or otherwise missing drives.
if you can find a descriptive enough answer from these comments I'll happily mark it and upvote.

Comment: You should not use RAID5 - another drive failure is way too likely when you are replacing a failed drive.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I suppose that's true in a high-availability cluster. this is just a home PC, the most use my array gets is when I'm downloading a movie and listening to music at the same time. and I offline it every time it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own work with arrays recently, I have found that drive naming often changes from one boot to another - my OS was created on what was then `sda1`, and on recent boots while attempting to recover from failed hardware I've discovered that sometimes the boot drive ends up as `sdc1` and sometimes as `sdf1` (yes, that particular machine has a lot of drives). In a case like this where `mdadm` reports a drive that you had thought was part of a set has no superblock, the first thing to confirm is which of the drives on the system actually made up the RAID array in question. If you are running a GUI, you should have a tool available named `Disks` that will show you all the hard drives in the system, along with their current usage. From the command line, `sudo parted -l` will show you that information.

Once you're certain which of the drives make up the still-valid four of your five-disk set, you can then use `mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sd{a,c,d,f}1 missing` (using your example, and assuming that you confirmed that it was in fact `sda1`, `sdc1`, `sdd1`, and `sdf1` which made up the RAID set). Note the use of the keyword `missing` for a drive name, that's a flag to tell `mdadm` that there should be another drive there but it's not (yet) available. Strictly speaking that may not be necessary; the superblock will contain geometry information that shows this as a five-disk array and will try to rebuild it as a degraded array. Others may say that you have to be careful about matching the original disk order; my own experience says that while that was necessary in the past, more modern systems seem to record the disk's position in the array as part of the superblock, and even when device names change (as they did for me), the array will rebuild itself successfully.

In your case, I must admit I suspect something happening to that array while you weren't looking. The only way I can see that `sdc` could have ended up with a recovery partition is if it came out of a computer. I'd be curious to know if that array was already degraded when the more recent drive failed; I'd probably go to the length of checking serial numbers to see if it is the drive I thought I'd put in there. It's certain, however it happened, that when the drive got added to the system, it was not actually added to the array; home office RAID hardware will usually add a new drive into the array automatically, whoever did the physical drive exchange may have thought that your system did the same.

I'll also note one thing mentioned in the comments. Google did publish some time back that drives from the same batch do tend to fail at the same time; a RAID array made up of disks purchased at the same time in a lot from one supplier is likely to lose a second drive while attempting to rebuild an array after the first drive in that array fails. If I'm building a RAID5 array, I will deliberately purchase from several different suppliers, and often from several different manufacturers, to decrease the risk of getting multiple drives from the same batch. As you've been replacing drives over time, you very likely already are protected from this particular failure mode.

Comment: yeah. this is my home PC. I mostly have music, backups from family members, pics, videos, etc... it's not really something I pay much attention to, or that has much critical info. I was able to restore most of what I needed (my dad lost some masters he made a few years ago in his studio), so it's fine. I'll probably migrate to a RAID-6 array when I find the time.